# Firefox outline:none on input text is not working

Tags: javascript, firefox

outline:none works in Safari,Chrome, but not in Firefox

html:

```
<input type='text'>
```

css:

```
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

I tried

```
input, textarea {outline:none;}
input:active, textarea:active {outline:none;}
*:focus {outline:none;}
```

and

```
input:focus { outline: none !important;}
```

But failed, see feedle: http://jsfiddle.net/kotapaulta/sfycojn3/

How could I remove blue border in input text in Firefox on focus (version 31.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border`:

```
input:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
    border: 0 none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/egm8xwwa/

Comment: @theringostarrs: In what way?  I just tested in Chrome and Firefox and it works fine.